# unable to send int array from javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web app in which i have a model which looks like the following

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Routes { get; set; }
}
```

and in my javascript i have data like

```
var Routes = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        Routes.push(a);
    }
    var model = {
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'TEST',
        Routes: JSON.stringify(Routes)
    };
```

and in my ajax call it looks like

```
Data: model
```

but my **`Routes`** are being converted into string
if i write

```
var model = {
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'TEST',
        Routes: Routes
    };
```

then 
`**int[] Routes**` in **model**   is shows null
and if i write
    contentType: "json",
in my Ajax call then,
data of my model is shows null

what should i do if i want a array of int and don't want to convert that into string

Comment: if the data comes null then its not getting serialize properly on server side.. or server code condition returns null for that request. check why server is returning null

Comment: need the controller action code and the ajax code as well really. But stringifying your Routes array makes no sense, certainly.

Comment: Stringify the whole model like this `data: JSON.stringify(model)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared how you are sending the data using ajax. So i am making some assumptions and giving you a generic answer which might help you.

The [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Jav) method converts a javaScript object to it's corresponding JSON string. So when you execute the line `JSON.stringify(Routes)`, you get a **string** with value `[0,1,2,3,4]`. So basically the JSON object you are trying to send looks some like this

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "TEST",
    "Routes": "[0,1,2,3,4]"
}
```

You can see that `Routes` property value **is a string**, not an int array. When this data is sent to the server, the default model binder see that as a string(*which can contain anything*) and there is no way it will be mapped to an int array.

What you should be doing is, setting the `Routes` property value as the int array. When sending the data via ajax, you may convert the entire json object to the it's string equivalent using `JSON.stringify` and use the resulting string as the `data` property of the ajax call, while specifying  the `content-type` header value as `application/json`.

```
var routes = [];
for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    routes.push(a);
}

var model = { ID: 1, Name: 'TEST', Routes: routes };

$.ajax({
    url: "/YourUrlToYourActionMethodAjaxPost",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json"

}).done(function (result) {
    console.log('result', result);
}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

The `JSON.stringify(model)` line will result in the below string in the request  string value and that is what we are sending to the server.

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"TEST","Routes":[0,1,2,3,4]}
```

This should work assuming you have an action method which uses `Data` class as it's parameter type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(Data model)
{
   // to do : do something with model
   // to do : return something   
}
```